# How to get a Schengen tourist visa as a nomad freelancer with a foreign company? (Morocco)

Tags: visa, schengen, europe, self-employment

I'm a citizen of Morocco and I have a legal US company (in the software industry), and a US business bank account with a decent revenue (i never travelled to US or europe).

How can i prove ties to my home country? i'm afraid of applying for a tourist visa and getting denied because I don't have a local company in my home country (which I don't want to do because my clients aren't local and it wouldn't help me logistically)

I checked the required documents for self-employed on all european consulates websites in Morocco and they all list documents only a locally registered company would have.

Anyone in this same situation and got a visa like this in a developing country?

P.S. I know it's tricky now because of Covid, but i'm thinking ahead.

Comment: Have you looked at the consulate requirements **in the US** to see what form from US firms are required? Since your firm is a US firm, that may be acceptable even though you are making the application as a resident of Morocco.

Comment: @CodeOverload What ties to Morocco **do** you have? What is your travel history like, especially to countries with comparably strict entry criteria? Related question https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/103826/how-to-prove-that-you-have-significant-ties-with-family-in-your-home-country

Comment: I need a visa for the US too, i'm not a US citizen (i'm from Morocco), i never got a visa to europe or the US before. i did go to southeast asia years ago.

Comment: I don't own any home/car, but i have an income of ~$3k/mo